# Java: How to put an icon inside a jar (or exe)? What is the path to it?

Tags: java, icons

What I would like to do is change the icon of my program when it runs.

Code I've found is:

```
      try {
          String imagePath = "res/Image.png";
          InputStream imgStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(imagePath );
          BufferedImage myImg;
          myImg = ImageIO.read(imgStream);
          this.setIconImage(myImg);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

My question is: where do I put my image and how do I get its path? End result would be to have an .exe (or worst case a .jar) that I would just have to transfer, so I'd like to have the icon inside the exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Class.getResource(String name) expects a resource name relative to the location the class is loaded from. So if your resource is called image.jpg, then image.jpg must be in the same folder where the class is whose getResource() method you're calling.
```

You can also specify an absolute folder inside the jar if you start it with the / character:

```
getClass().getResource("/resources/images/image.jpg");
```

In this case the image.jpg must be in the /resources/images folder inside the jar or in your source folder (which will be copied to the bin folder by your IDE).